# Freshly installed Visual Studio 2015 completely changed upon restart of IDE

Tags: windows-8, visual-studio-2015, windows-10, intellisense, microsoft-account

I am using windows 10. I have installed VB 2015 for several times. For some reason my white backgrounded design is modified to black, intellisense does not work for CSS and Javascript, Visual Studio does not even recognize them as languages and my Tools menu is truncated, for instance the Extensions and Updates menu item does not appear at all. The strange thing is that after installation everything worked impeccably and when I closed the IDE and reopened it, the problems I mentioned started to cause headaches. I have attached a few pictures to illustrate the problem.

### Language Issue Illustration

[image: Languages]

### Extensions and Updates Illustration

[image: Truncated Menu]

### Code without Intellisense (*painful*)

[image]

FYI: I first installed Visual Studio 2015 with the Microsoft account of my husband, who has Windows 8, but I created one for myself when I saw the problems and I am working with that now. Maybe his settings are synchronized with my IDE, I do not know. I do not know how to resolve the issue, this problem persisted for days. How could I make sure that my installation's settings remain as they were set, languages remain recognized and Extensions and Updates remain inside the Tools menu?